# Mint 14 does not detect my first hard disk

Tags: linux, linux-mint, grub, hard-disk

I have two hardisks installed in my machine :

```
Samsung SSD PM830  SATA : 128 Gb
ST9500423AS ATA : 500 Gb
```

When I start Mint installer, it only showed me the 500Gb harddisk.So I partitioned it into two 250Gb partitions and installed Mint on one of them.
But after rebooting,it didnt show any Grub/boot menu and directly loaded Windows 7.

Any tips?

Comment: is the windows on the 500gb hard disk or in 128gb hdd?

Comment: 128 Gb (sda) 500gb (sdb)

Comment: which hdds have windows and mint?

Comment: If Linux "sees" /dev/sda, that is a good sign. Can you mount the partitions on /dev/sda?

Comment: 128 Gb - Windows 7 , 500Gb - partitioed into 150Gb and 350Gb and Mint is installed on 350Gb . I noticed that when i choose the 500Gb hard as the boot device, Grub kicks off.